# Let $f(x)=\frac{x\ln x}{1+x}$,evaluate $\lim _{m\to f\left(x_0\right)+}\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_0}{m+x_0}$.

Tags: limits, mathematical-physics

Let $f(x)=\frac{x\ln x}{1+x}$,suppose $x_0$is the extreme point of $f$.For $m\in \mathbb{R} $,it's easy to see  that if $m>f(x_0)=-x_0$,then the equation $f(x)=m$ has exactly two real roots $x_1,x_2$,$x_1<x_0<x_2$.The question is how to evaluate the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim _{m\to f\left(x_0\right)+}\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_0}{m+x_0}？
\end{align*}
To this problem,we can see that if $m\to f(x_0)+$,then $x_1\to x_0^-$,and $x_2\to x_0^+$.By Taylor's formula we have
$$f(x_1)-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x_1-x_0)+\frac12f''(\xi)(x_1-x_0)^2=\frac12f''(\xi)(x_1-x_0)^2,$$
where $\xi \in (x_1,x_0)$.So
$$m+x_0\sim \frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(x_1-x_0)^2.$$
But I can't handle $x_1+x_2-2x_0$.If we can expand $x_1+x_2-2x_0$ as  terms of power of $(x_1-x_0)$,then it must be
$$x_1+x_2-2x_0\sim k(x_1-x_0)^2.$$
But how can I get it?Maybe there are other ways.

Answer (score 3):

The essence of this question is to expand the roots (technically functional inverses for the multivalued function presented above) in a series around the minimum, where they coincide. As demonstrated by @ClaudeLeibovici above, a second-order approximation is required to evaluate the limit, and we will find that for a general function $f(z)$. Suppose that at $z=z_0$ the function attains a critical point with $f(z_0)=\zeta,f'(z_0)=0, f''(z_0)\neq 0$. Denote the two local branches of the inverse with $f^{-1}_{\pm}(z),f^{-1}_{\pm}(\zeta)=z_0$, where the plus/minus branch indicates the root that in some disk around the critical point obeys $(f^{-1}_+(z)>z_0)/(f^{-1}_-(z)<z_0)$.

How do we find successive monomial approximations to these? It is not a priori clear what the form is close to the critical point, so we try to evaluate the first-order limit

$$L_{1,\pm}=\lim_{z\to \zeta}\frac{f_{\pm}^{-1}(z)-z_0}{(z-\zeta)^a}$$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is to be defined such that the limit above exists and is finite. Perform the change of variables $z=f(t)$:

$$L_{1,\pm}=\lim_{t\to z_0^{\pm}}\frac{t-z_0}{(f(t)-\zeta)^a}$$
Given the Taylor series expansion $f(t)-\zeta=\frac{f''(z_0)}{2}(t-z_0)^2+\mathcal{O}((t-z_0)^3)$ around $z_0$ we readily deduce that for this limit to be finite the exponent needs to take on the value $a=1/2$ and the limit evaluates to

$$L_{1,\pm}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{f''(z_0)}}$$

Following the same thought process we can continue to compute succesive approximations by subtracting the last approximation from the series and dividing by an appropriate power of $z-\zeta$. For the second-order approximation it looks like this:

$$L_{2,\pm}=\lim_{z\to \zeta}\frac{f^{-1}_{\pm}(z)-z_0-(\pm)\sqrt{\frac{2}{f''(z_0)}}\sqrt{z-\zeta}}{(z-\zeta)^a}=\lim_{z\to z_0^{\pm}}\frac{t-z_0-(\pm)\sqrt{\frac{2}{f''(z_0)}}\sqrt{f(t)-\zeta}}{(f(t)-\zeta)^a}$$

We expand the numerator to second order to find that

$$t-z_0-\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{f''(z_0)}(f(t)-\zeta)}=\frac{f'''(z_0)}{6f''(z_0)}(t-z_0)^2+\mathcal{O}((t-z_0)^{3})$$

Thus $a=1$ and the limit evaluates to

$$L_{2,\pm}=-\frac{f'''(z_0)}{3(f''(z_0))^2}$$

We have computed enough terms to calculate the desired limit. In this notation it can be written

$$\mathcal{L}=\lim_{m\to f(x_0)}\frac{f^{-1}_{+}(m)+f^{-1}_{-}(m)-2x_0}{m-f(x_0)}=2L_{2,\pm}=-\frac{2}{3}\frac{f'''(x_0)}{(f''(x_0))^2}\approx 1.40924 $$

This calculation hints at the fact that there is a generalization of Lagrange's inversion theorem around a critical point. I have not been able to find a general formula for the coefficients of the branches of the inverse, but I think it is possible to obtain such a formula.

It also turns out that there is an exact solution to this equation! Set in the original equation $z=\ln x-m$ which transforms it to the form $ze^z=m e^{-m}$ which admits two solutions

$$x_1(m)=\frac{m}{W_0(me^{-m})}~,~ x_2(m)=\frac{m}{W_{-1}(me^{-m})}$$

However this form is not particularly useful for obtaining expansions.

Comment: (+1) Your solution is very nice. It gives the limit for general $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering
$$f(x)=\frac{x \log (x)}{x+1}$$ (which trivially cancels at $x=0$ and $x=1$), we have
$$f'(x)=\frac{x+\log (x)+1}{(x+1)^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=-\frac{x^2+2 x \log (x)-1}{x (x+1)^3}$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

We have
$$f(x_*)=-W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x_*)=\frac{1}{W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) \left(W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)+1\right)}$$ So, $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum of the function.

Now expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x_*$ and get
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2 + O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ and then the *approximation* of the roots $(x_1,x_2)$ when $f(x)=m$
$$x_1=x_*-\sqrt{2 x_* \left(x_*+1\right)}   \sqrt{m+x_*}$$
$$x_2=x_*+\sqrt{2 x_* \left(x_*+1\right)}   \sqrt{m+x_*}$$

I think that now, you have a sufficient number of elements to finish properly your work.

**Edit**

The above approximation is not sufficient at all; it is only acceptable very  close to $x_*$.

A much better approximation is given by the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant
$$g(x)=\frac{18 x_*^3 (x_*+1)+6 x_*^2 (4 x_*+1) (x-x_*)+5 (x_*-2) x_* (x-x_*)^2 } {-18 \left(x_*^2 (x_*+1)\right)-6 (x_* (4 x_*+1)) (x-x_*)+(1-5 x_*) (x-x_*)^2 }$$

$$\Phi=\int_0^1 \big[f(x)-g(x)\big]^2\, dx= 2.56 \times 10^{-5}$$

and we are left with a quadratic equation in $(x-x_*)$. This gives
$$\Delta=x_1+x_2-2x_*=\frac{6 x_* (4 x_*+1) (x_*+m) } {9 x_*+(1-5 x_*) (x_*+m)}$$
which would give
$$\lim _{m\to f\left(x_0\right)+}\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_0}{m+x_0}=\frac{2}{3} (4 x_*+1)$$

For illustration purposes, I used $m=-0.15$. The approximation gives
$$x_1=0.05166\qquad \qquad x_2=0.69003\qquad \qquad \Delta=0.18475$$ while the exact solutions are
$$x_1=0.05428\qquad \qquad x_2=0.69324\qquad \qquad \Delta=0.19059$$

**Numerical checks**

Using the above was computed the value of
$$R_k=\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_0}{m+x_0}\qquad\text{with}\qquad m=(1-10^{-k}) f(x_0)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & R_k \\
 1 & 1.424602322711298857 \\
 2 & 1.410758744957374844 \\
 3 & 1.409390617211381501 \\
 4 & 1.409253962752398454 \\
 5 & 1.409240298885867560 \\
 6 & 1.409238932515004374 \\
 7 & 1.409238795878075951
\end{array}
\right)$$ while
$$\frac{2}{3} (4 x_*+1)=1.409238780696196787$$

Comment: So $x_1+x_2-2x_*=0$?I'm afraid it's not the truth.

Comment: @mbfkk. You are correct. This is only true very close to $x_*$. I am working the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts**

*Remark*: Actually, $x_1 = \mathrm{e}^{W_{-1}(m\mathrm{e}^{-m}) + m}$ and $x_2 = \mathrm{e}^{W_0(m\mathrm{e}^{-m}) + m}$.
But we avoid using it.

The desired limit is $\frac83 W_0(\mathrm{e}^{-1}) + \frac23$ where $W_0(\cdot)$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W function, as @Claude Leibovici pointed out.

*Fact 1*: $f(x) = \frac{x\ln x}{x + 1}$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, x_0)$ and strictly increasing on $(x_0, \infty)$, where $x_0 = W_0(\mathrm{e}^{-1})$ is the unique minimizer of $f(x)$ on $(0, \infty)$.
(Note: From $f'(x) = 0$, we have $\ln x + x + 1 = 0$
that is $x\mathrm{e}^x = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$ which results in $x = W_0(\mathrm{e}^{-1})$.)

Let $m \in (-x_0, 0)$. The equation $f(x) = m$ has exactly two real solution $0 < x_1 < x_0 < x_2 < 1$.

WLOG, assume $m \in (-x_0, -x_0 + 1/10)$.

Let
\begin{align*}
 y_1 &= x_0 - \sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)(m + x_0)} + \left(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13\right)(m + x_0) - (m + x_0)^{3/2}, \\
 y_2 &= x_0 - \sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)(m + x_0)} + \left(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13\right)(m + x_0), \\
 z_1 &= x_0 + \sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)(m + x_0)} + \left(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13\right)(m + x_0), \\
 z_2 &= x_0 + \sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)(m + x_0)} + \left(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13\right)(m + x_0) + (m + x_0)^{3/2}.
\end{align*}
It is easy to prove that
$0 < y_1 < y_2 < x_0 < z_1 < z_2 < 1$.

*Fact 2*: $f(y_1) > m$, $f(y_2) < m$, $f(z_1) < m$, and $f(z_2) > m$
for all $m \in (-x_0, -x_0 + 1/10)$.

By Facts 1-2, we have $y_1 < x_1 < y_2$
and $z_1 < x_2 < z_2$. Thus,
$y_1 + z_1 < x_1 + x_2 < y_2 + z_2$.
Then, we easily obtain
$\lim_{m \to (-x_0)^{+}} \frac{x_1 + x_2 - 2x_0}{m + x_0} = \frac83 W_0(\mathrm{e}^{-1}) + \frac23$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 2*:

We prove $f(y_1) > m$ only. The rest is similar.

It suffices to prove that
$\ln y_1 > m + \frac{m}{y_1}$.
With the substitution $u^2 = m + x_0$ ($0 < u < 1/\sqrt{10}$), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\ln \left(x_0 - u\sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)} + \left(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13\right)u^2 - u^3\right)\\
 &> u^2 - x_0 + \frac{u^2 - x_0}{x_0 - u\sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)} + (\frac43 x_0 + \frac13)u^2 - u^3}.
\end{align*}
Denote $\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}$ by $F(u)$. We have, for all $u \in (0, 1/\sqrt{10})$,
\begin{align*}
 F'(u) &= \frac{u^3(q_4u^4 + q_3u^3 + q_2u^2 + q_1u + q_0)}{9[x_0 - u\sqrt{2x_0(1 + x_0)} +(\frac43 x_0 + \frac13)u^2 - u^3]^2}\\
 &> 0
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 q_4 &= -18, \\
 q_3 &= 48\,x_0+12, \\
 q_2 &= -36\sqrt{2x_0 \left( 1+x_0 \right) }-32\,x_0^{2}-16\,x_0+25, \\
 q_1 &= 48x_0\sqrt{2x_0 \left( 1+x_0 \right) }+12\sqrt {2x_0
  \left( 1+x_0 \right) }-24\,x_0-24, \\
 q_0 &= 36\sqrt{2x_0 \left( 1+x_0 \right) }-52\,x_0^{2}-32\,x_0+2.
\end{align*}
Also, $F(0) = 0$. Thus, $F(u) > 0$ for all $u  \in (0, 1/\sqrt{10})$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not expect any bounty for this, just wanted to share my thoughts.

Note that in this problem we have implicitly defined functions $x_1(m)$ and $x_2(m)$.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7ikozp9knl) is a graph displaying $x_1(m)$ and $x_2(m)$. (Their graphs lie in the second quadrant and are traced out in black as we use the slider to move $m$ closer to $-x_0$.)

The limit we seek,  $\displaystyle L:= \lim_{m \rightarrow f(x_0)^+} \frac{x_1(m)+x_2(m)-2x_0}{m+x_0}$,  is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ so we can try to apply L'Hopital's Rule.  Unfortunately, doing so yields $\displaystyle L= \lim_{m \rightarrow f(x_0)^+} \frac{x_1'(m) + x_2'(m)}{1}$ which evaluates to $-\infty + \infty$.

Note that we can also split the limit into two parts to obtain  $$\displaystyle L= \lim_{m \rightarrow f(x_0)^+} \frac{x_2(m)-x_0}{m - (-x_0)} +\lim_{m \rightarrow f(x_0)^+} \frac{x_1(m)-x_0}{m - (-x_0)}.$$

The difference quotients that appear in the above expression are the slopes of secant lines from $(-x_0,x_0)$ to $(m, x_2(m))$ and from $(-x_0,x_0)$ to $(m, x_1(m))$, respectively.  The first represents a positive slope while the second a negative one.  Perhaps these slopes cancel in a controlled way as $m \rightarrow -x_0$ so the limit of their sum exists (as a real number), but I expect they do not.

Comment: I also thought about $\lim x_1'(m) + x_2'(m)$ where $x_1(m), x_2(m)$ are expressed in terms of the Lambert W function. However, I can not get the limit.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not split the limit into two parts.

Comment: You are right about that.  "Breaking down" the limit (over $+,-,\cdot, \text{ or } \div$) is only justified $\textit{if}$ the resulting limits exist as elements of $\mathbb{R}$.  Since here we have $\pm \infty$ it is not justified.

Comment: As I alluded to in the last sentence of my original answer, if we calculate each of these slopes $\textit{before}$ taking the limit (i.e. before splitting the limit) it is possible that the slopes cancel in a controlled way so that the limit of the sum does exist (even though if we try to split the limit and take them separately we get $\infty + (- \infty)$.

Comment: As a quick example, if we change the original problem that was posted so that instead $f(x)= -\sqrt{1/9-(x-1/3)^2}$ (i.e. lower half of a circle with center $(1/3,0)$ and radius $1/3$) we have a very similar problem. ([Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x5tplkreik) is a Desmos graph of this modified problem.)  By symmetry the the slopes involved sum to $0$ for every value of $m$, so the limit as $m \rightarrow -x_0$ is $0$, although if we split the limit first we get $\infty + (-\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, the two limits does not exist (finite), but the limit of the sum of the expressions exists (something is cancelled). My answer gives the exact terms of  the two separate expressions.